# How to remove last char in oversized string php

Tags: php, string

Something strange happens here, I have for example a string printend by var_dump:

```
 string(83) "papillon"
```

This string has a length oversized, is 83, the real is 8. 
Anyway some strings have a `!` in final position : `papillon!`
If they has just 1 or more then 1 of `!` i have to remove the last.

```
 if(substr_count($tit, '!') >= 1){
            $tit = str_replace('!','',$tit);
          }
```

This is not correct, also i can't use `substr()` becouse of the size. So how I can remove the last occurence of a specific char in a string?

Comment: `rtrim($tit, "!");` [rtrim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) takes a mask of chars you want to be removed from the right hand of the string, there is also `ltrim` for left hand chars

Comment: What exactly is the problem with using `substr`?

Comment: @NicoHaase the length of the string is 83 not 8, so in the last position is not !

Comment: I would recommend that you make a debug output of the value using `urlencode` first in such cases … that will allow you to see the actual bytes values in those positions that are simply ”non-printable” (or maybe even invalid) “characters”.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, there are a couple of options;

Opt A : [rtrim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php)
So, if you have;

```
$my_string = "This is a really long string!!!";
print rtrim($my_string, "!");
// Printed; This is a really long string
```

This removes all occurrences of the mask of chars chosen

Opt B : [regex with preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)
So, again we have the following string and work;

```
$my_string = "This is a really long string!!!";
print preg_replace("/(.+)(!){1}/i", "$0", $my_string);
// Printed; This is a really long string!!
```

Using preg_replace only removes the final occurrence of the "!" in the string, leaving you with 2 remaining

This greatly depends on what you need and of course there are other options such as substr, as follows;

```
$my_string = "This is a really long string!!!";
print substr($my_string, 0, -1);
// Printed; This is a really long string!!
```

So that worked the same as preg_replace, but you could also count the amount of exclamation points and removed as needed

So, I went away and realised I was using a JavaScript regex playground rather than PHP which caused issues... (oops!)
To which end, I came up with the following when messing around on a PHP testbed [as shown in my working out](https://tehplayground.com/KvetkAm9eChPKWYB)

```
$my_string = "This is a really long string!!!";
print preg_replace("/(.[!]{1})[!]{0,}/i", "$1", $my_string);
```

This removes every "!" except one, if you wanted all gone, change to;

```
$my_string = "This is a really long string!!!";
print preg_replace("/(.)[!]{0,}/i", "$1", $my_string);
```

It doesn't matter how many additional "!" there are (I've tested with 103), either all, or all but one will be removed

Comment: When I do $my_string = preg_replace("/(.+)(!){1}/i", "$0", $my_string, "!"); it delete me all the string, why?

Comment: Could be the test bed I used, try with `$1` in place of `$0`

Comment: Nope, same error.Also rtrim can't help me, neither substr, only regex can save me

Comment: @Cristian - I am working on improving this currently, please bear with me

Comment: @Cristian - I have added an edit to the bottom of my answer, hope this helps

Comment: Perfect, you saved me ! Thank you